# mySQL - ¿Cómo calcular código MD5 y guardarlo en una celda?

Tags: mysql, md5

Muy buenas!

Quiero calcular el código MD5 en cada una de las líneas de mi tabla y guardarlo en la columna A. ¿Se puede hacer en mySQL?

Por ejemplo, coger el valor de la columna B, calcular el MD5 y guardarlo en la columna A, y hacer esto en todas las filas de la tabla.

¿Alguna idea?
Mil gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería algo asi como

```
update nombre_tabla set columnaA = md5(columnaB)
```

Comment: No sabía que mySQL tenía la función md5. Sorry entonces por la pregunta, estupida por mi parte :'( Mil gracias!